# TFX Example_Gen Produce RuntimeError

Tags: python, runtime-error, tensorflow2.0, tfx

I've been getting the following error when I run `context.run(example_gen)` , and I like to understand what does it mean and how can I avoid getting the error. Please advice and thanks in advance!

**Error:** `RuntimeError: Files in same split /home/jupyter/.../data/* have different header.`

The data is a csv with headers of "A,B,C,D"

```
from  tfx.proto import example_gen_pb2

base_dir = '/home/jupyter/.../data/'
#Input has a single split 'input_dir/*
#Output 2 splits: train:eval=3:1.'
output = example_gen_pb2.Output(
            split_config=example_gen_pb2.SplitConfig(splits=[
                example_gen_pb2.SplitConfig.Split(name='train', hash_buckets=3),
                example_gen_pb2.SplitConfig.Split(name='eval', hash_buckets=1)
            ]))

examples = csv_input(os.path.join(base_dir))
example_gen = CsvExampleGen(input=examples, output_config=output)
```

Answer (score 2):

We've had the same error. In our case the directory also contained hidden files. To be more precise, a jupyter notebook checkpoint directory.

To fix this issue: make sure the directory only contains .csv files. No other (hidden) files.

Credits for [this comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/issues/2197#issuecomment-662751292) on github.